# RabbitMQ Filter Messages using Shovel/Header based shovel

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

Is there any option to filter messages when using Shovel.
For example,
vhost1 > exchange1 > filter set of messages > vhost2 > exchange2.

or using header exchange
vhost1 > header-exchange1 > header based filtering > vhost2 > queue2